# Facebook Graph API - Is it possible to retrieve posts on a wall from other users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve all user posts that have been posted on a facebook wall by other users (example: User A posted on RedWidgets' wall a question, User B posted on RedWidgets's wall a testimonial, etc.). The only thing I found so far is using an FQL ("SELECT message FROM stream WHERE type = 56") but that's deprecated and can't use it. 56 is the code for "Post on wall from another user" (see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/))

I can't find nothing in Facebook's documentation about this sort of thing besides FQL. Where should I look?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the feeds of a page using graph api.If you have a valid access token (page or user) you can use graph api to fetch the feeds and then check whether for each post owner.if it is not by the page , it will be by other users. You can try the below code

```
$fb_page = ''     // Facebook page name
$fb_page_id = ''  // Facebook Page id
$access_token = ''  //your access token
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/".$fb_page.'/feed?access_token='.$access_token;
$curl = curl_init($url);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
$result = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl); 
$details = json_decode($result,true);
$posts = $details['data'];
foreach ($posts as $post)
{
    if($post['from']['id'] != $fb_page_id) 
    {
        echo "<p>".$post['message']."</p>"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's actually a good solution. Thanks. I see that each status has a status_type. The type I want is wall_post. Is there anyway to filter out only posts with status_type = wall_post? I want this because I can't receive all the posts using the graph api so I'm forced to use pagination.

Comment: There is no option for searching only for status_type = wall_post. Post search is deprecated . If you want to get higher number of posts in a single fetch you can use limit to the query. You can put limit = 500 . If you are using limit then update above answer with this $url =      "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/".$fb_page.'/feed?access_token='.$access_token.'&limit=500';